# Store hidden value (id) in ListView

Tags: c#, listview, hidden

I have a ListView where I show a list of objects (persons) with their relevant properties, which are: name (string), age (int). 
But this objects have also an id property, that is used to differentiate them from each other.

The question is, **what is the 'correct' way to store the id value**, to retrieve it when I click on the item that represents the object?

To do this I am using a hidden column (column width = 0) but I think that it isn't a good way.

```
foreach (var person in col.listPersons )
{
    ListViewItem lIt = new ListViewItem(person.id); //Column with width = 0
    lIt.SubItems.Add(person.name);
    lIt.SubItems.Add(person.age);
    lPer.Items.Add(lIt) //Add the item to ListView
}
```

Comment: The "correct way" would be to use a DataGridView so that everything isnt converted to string (or boxed as Object using the Tag),  Dates will stay dates, ints will remain ints and so forth

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple way of adding extra data attributes is to use the `Tag` property. You can assign a class object with multiple properties or a simple scalar value such as your id. Tag is quite versatile and is a common property on many controls.

Our person definition.

```
public class Person
{
    public long id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}
```

Example 1: Assign the id to the ListViewItem Tag property.

```
foreach (var person in col.listPersons)
{
    ListViewItem lIt = new ListViewItem();
    lIt.Tag = person.id;
    lIt.SubItems.Add(person.name);
    lIt.SubItems.Add(person.age.ToString());
    lPer.Items.Add(lIt); // Add the item to ListView
}
```

You can then easily retrieve the id value back again:

```
ListViewItem lit = sender as ListViewItem;
person.id = (long)lit.Tag;
```

Example 2: Assign the whole person object to the ListViewItem Tag property.

```
foreach (var person in col.listPersons)
{
    ListViewItem lIt = new ListViewItem();
    lIt.Tag = person;
    lIt.SubItems.Add(person.name);
    lIt.SubItems.Add(person.age.ToString());
    lPer.Items.Add(lIt); // Add the item to ListView
}
```

Just as easily, get the person object back again:

```
ListViewItem lit = sender as ListViewItem;
person = (Person)lit.Tag;
```

Example 3: Another common way is to Use the `ListViewItem.Name` property. The name is treated like a Key in the ListView. You can then use this key value to pass to ListView.Items.IndexOfKey() or ListView.Items["key"] in order to search the ListView for a specific item. The Name is a string and as such isn't as flexible as the Tag, but this may be more ideal for your use case.

```
foreach (var person in col.listPersons)
{
    ListViewItem lIt = new ListViewItem();
    lIt.Name = person.id; // Treat the Name as a Key
    lIt.SubItems.Add(person.name);
    lIt.SubItems.Add(person.age);
    lPer.Items.Add(lIt); // Add the item to ListView

    // Retrieve the person back from the ListViewItemCollection by index.
    var personIndex = lPer.Items.IndexOfKey(person.id.ToString());
    var lItA = lPer.Items[personIndex];

    // Retrieve the person back from the ListViewItemCollection by key.
    var lItB = lPer.Items[person.id.ToString()];
}
```

Comment: It's exactly what I need.
PD: Buen nick :)